# This burnination was perfectly [balance]d

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

As-of September 2016: [Questions tagged with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/balance):

- 91 questions
- 3 tag watchers
- no usage guidance

As-of October 2020:

- 166 questions
- 12 tag watchers
- no usage guidance, but a tag wiki:

> [balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/balance) is used in its general meaning, from audio balancing to whether a string is balanced (e.g. has as many opening parentheses as closing one), etc., so you are encouraged to use one or more additional tags to better describe your situation.

This clearly describes a meta-tag with a general meaning that can't stand alone.

Of the past 30 questions, topics include:

- an account balance in a financial app/api/query (10)
- balanced binary trees (5)
- balanced word lists/SQL columns/data percentages/cusums (3)
- image white balance (4)
- cloud server loadbalancing (2)
- algorithm to balance sports team attributes (2)
- chemical imbalance (in a code function)
- a balanced fluid model
- balancing parentheses in code
- balancing GUI repaints

The voting on the most recent 58 questions is pretty balanced with mostly 0, a few scattered upvotes and downvotes for a net +2.  Prior to that there are a few more questions with higher votes, but at this point there's likely survivorship bias in play.  48.5% of the questions have gone unanswered. No answerer has answered more than one question; the top scorer on the badge has a single 24-vote answer on balanced string (corresponding to the wiki).

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No.

There are questions related to accounting, although exact context of operation varies significantly:

- [How to calculate account balance properly on SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477659/account-balance-how-to-calculate-it-properly-on-sql)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873309/odoo-import-opening-balance-customers
- [Calculating Interest (Java), the program should print the projected account balance after an arbitrary numbers of years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841708/calculating-interest-java-the-program-should-print-the-projected-account-bala)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502771/calculate-daily-balance-with-elasticsearch-kibana
- [PayPal Soap API Balance for certain Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945920/paypal-soap-api-balance-for-certain-date)

There are questions related to tree as a data structure being balanced:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343621/check-a-tree-is-balanced-why-my-code-does-not-work
- [Check if n-ary tree is balanced in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232817/check-if-n-ary-tree-is-balanced-in-common-lisp)

There are questions where balance is used as a synonym of [load-balancing].

- [HAProxy balancer using the url_param value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331133/haproxy-balancer-using-the-url-param-value)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593528/balancer-and-web-server-in-ruby

And there are some random questions which does not fit for any 'common' group:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378903/send-data-to-com-connected-shimadzu-electronic-balance-auy-220-success
- [R remove rows from panel while keeping the panel balanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671246/r-elegant-way-to-balance-unbalanced-panel-data)

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Sure, problems listed above may be a valid question related to programming

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Due to it's ambiguousness it does not. Either it's better described by another tag (e.g. [load-balancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load-balancing)) or it describes business logic, when tags tend to define technical aspect of problem.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Samples from first question clearly shows that it does not mean same thing in all common concepts.

Comment: I think the answer is "no" for the question N°2. A valid problem related to programming could involve anything, but "balance" is not a programming concept / tool / topic *per se* . Otherwise you could have "gardening" , "cooking" or "fly" deemed on-topic.

Comment: I upvoted the question and the answer in times past (so I can't vote again).  What can I do to promote the tag's demise?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This question is now in the burnination process. Unless there is a serious objection mounted, the tag will be burninated. Your votes (regardless of when they were made) are a part of that process. In a day or so, feel free to help burninate the tag

Answer (score 16):

I think we should definitely lose our [balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/balance).

Some of the more common tags should have a new tag created for them if they are programming related, such as [balanced-binary-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/balanced-binary-tree).

I initially considered one related to financial account balances in an on-topic way to support questions relating to financial APIs, calculations, etc. such as  [account-balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/account-balance), but that may not be on-topic enough. There is a [running-balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/running-balance) tag already for that use case. After considering the comments, I no longer think I am [interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interest)ed in such a tag.

The load balancing questions already have a generic [load-balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load-balance) tag available, as well as specific tags for nearly every cloud provider.

The "balanced parenthesis" problem citied in the tag wiki, and the source of the highest scoring answerer's score probably has a better name/tag to specify it, such as "valid brackets", although I'm not sure any tag is needed for a specific algorithm.

For the remainder of the questions, the tag adds nothing useful and should be burninated.

Comment: Is [account-balance] really a useful, on-topic tag?

Comment: @leonheess see the 5 on-topic questions under point 1 of OP and feel free to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: [account-balance] is not on-topic, and does not need a tag. Questions regarding account balances share nothing programming-related in common that requires them to be categorized together, or searched for, or followed, which are the uses for tags. I think we should close out the [account-balance] :).

Comment: Just because one can ask questions about something related to X, if X itself is not on topic, I don't see why we should create a tag about it. There's nothing different between account balance and an array of numbers from the programmers perspective. The purpose of the business logic is something that could be noted in the question body, not on the tags.

Comment: @HereticMonkey you're not `interest`ed in my `account-balance`? :(

Comment: @DanielWiddis It's starting to `compound` every time you mention it :).

Comment: @leonheess I would say no, it is not. There's nothing specifically programming-related that I can think of when I see a question is tagged with [account-balance]. I'd have to open the question to see how it is a relevant matter, which means it's not really a good tag.

Comment: @TylerH Exactly, that is what I was insinuating

Answer (score 4):

[balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/balance) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions about load balancing (provided they're about programming) could be tagged [load-balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load-balance)

## Progress:

The [balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/balance) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=balance),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbalance%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbalance%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbalance%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbalance%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=334764)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/balance) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/balance) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/balance) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.